# IONIC auto renewable In App purchase

Tags: cordova, ionic2, in-app-purchase

I am developing app with IONIC 2 in which I have auto renewable subscription.

I have used "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase". My problem is, I don't know how to track auto renewable subscription. How we will get to know that user's subscription is completed or renewed.

I tried using `restorepurchase` option but in that I get all the entries with state: 3 instead of getting active subscription.  Is it because I am using sandbox?

Comment: any luck with your query? I have the same concerns.